# In eclipse'view, how to create a shortcut

Tags: eclipse

For exzample, we can use up down arrows to select function in Outline(ctrl+o), how to create a shortcut (alt+i alt+k and so on) to map such action?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the shortcut keys on Eclips by going to Window > Preferences. Click on General > Keys.

Or follow the steps at this link:

[FAQ How do I provide a keyboard shortcut for my action?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F)

Comment: What do you mean? A plugin with defined shortcut keys?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986594/how-to-map-arrows-in-eclipses-special-windows